# Tick mark grouping by year in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a time series in which stem densities were measured both early and late in the growing season. I would like to present trends in stem densities over time, but including tick mark labels such as 2005 Early, 2005 Late, 2006 Early, 2006 Late, and so on is too cluttered for presentation. Is it possible to group the tick marks from each year, such that each mark indicates only either "Early" or "Late", with the year indicated below each pair?

Here is what I have come up with so far, but I know beforehand that it won't give me exactly what I have in mind, but worse yet, it doesn't work. It results in a plot without any x-axis tick labels whatsoever:

```
dt<-ggplot(nzsum, aes(x = Date, y = Average.Stem.Density, colour = Species)) + geom_line(aes(group = Species)) + 
geom_point() + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Average.Stem.Density-se, ymax=Average.Stem.Density+se), width = 0.25) + facet_grid(Heat~Treatment)
dt<-dt+ scale_x_discrete(breaks = 1:18, labels = c("2005 Early", "Late", "2006 Early", "Late", "2007 Early","Late","2008 Early", "Late",
"2009 Early","Late", "2010 Early","Late","2011 Early","Late","2012 Early","Late", "2013 Early","Late"))
dt + theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.5, size=10)) + ylab('Stem Density')
```

To possibly further complicate things, I have missing data for some of the measurement dates, but would like to have either the gaps remain in the plot, or to have a vertical line separating the periods of consistent measurements.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

output of dput, as requested:

```
   > dput(nzsum)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L), .Label = c("2005 Early", 
"2005 Late", "2006 Early", "2006 Late", "2007 Early", "2007 Late", 
"2008 Early", "2008 Late", "2009 Early", "2009 Late", "2010 Early", 
"2010 Late", "2011 Early", "2011 Late", "2012 Early", "2012 Late", 
"2013 Early", "2013 Late"), class = "factor"), Treatment = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Ambient Precipitation", 
"Increased Precipitation Variability"), class = "factor"), Heat = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Ambient Temperature", 
"Increased Temperature"), class = "factor"), Species = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A. gerardii", 
"S. nutans"), class = "factor"), N = c(6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6), Average.Stem.Density = c(59.75, 
52.4166666666667, 59.4166666666667, 38.8333333333333, 47.1666666666667, 
44.6666666666667, 34.6666666666667, 47.1666666666667, 45.5833333333333, 
51, 46.8333333333333, 40.8333333333333, 36.0833333333333, 43.5, 
30.9166666666667, 53.1666666666667, 59.9166666666667, 47.8333333333333, 
54.8333333333333, 40.1666666666667, 45.0833333333333, 38.5833333333333, 
38.6666666666667, 38.3333333333333, 41.5, 57.3333333333333, 41.4166666666667, 
50.25, 32.8333333333333, 41.5833333333333, 29.5, 41.25, 57.75, 
34, 49.4166666666667, 45.1666666666667, 36.5833333333333, 22.6666666666667, 
33.0833333333333, 30.1666666666667, 37.8333333333333, 43.9166666666667, 
34.3333333333333, 44.4166666666667, 30.6666666666667, 31.1666666666667, 
28.0833333333333, 41.0833333333333, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 52.8333333333333, 43.5, 39, 
38.4166666666667, 40.5833333333333, 28.8333333333333, 33.3333333333333, 
26.6666666666667, 34.5833333333333, 53.3333333333333, 24.6666666666667, 
38.8333333333333, 26.9166666666667, 35.3333333333333, 22.1666666666667, 
16.3333333333333, 51.0833333333333, 58.25, 34.8333333333333, 
46.5833333333333, 47.5, 40, 35.4166666666667, 29.0833333333333, 
24.5, 62, 20.1666666666667, 40.6666666666667, 22.9166666666667, 
50, 20.25, 23.25, 32, 45.1666666666667, 30, 36.5, 31.6666666666667, 
36.9166666666667, 21.6666666666667, 18.4166666666667, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 27.9166666666667, 29.75, 24.8333333333333, 
20.0833333333333, 19, 21.8333333333333, 15.5833333333333, 8.16666666666667, 
25, 42.25, 20.5833333333333, 29.25, 19.8333333333333, 23.1666666666667, 
19.4166666666667, 13.8333333333333, 46.6666666666667, 35, 36.4166666666667, 
29.4166666666667, 36, 22.6666666666667, 29.0833333333333, 18.5833333333333, 
33.3333333333333, 31.25, 25.8333333333333, 28.3333333333333, 
23.1666666666667, 14.0833333333333, 18.4166666666667, 15.3333333333333
), sd = c(32.2020962050609, 15.1407287363147, 25.7884017858158, 
14.1833235409289, 13.7501515143167, 22.0333081189972, 11.0574258607809, 
23.6107320231006, 25.6542718989775, 13.2815661727072, 15.4099534933324, 
11.2590704175197, 8.15730756234351, 15.52417469626, 11.8423674434915, 
20.9300422041301, 36.3612660212302, 14.7738507731284, 16.7022952514517, 
14.9788740119766, 7.61194237147567, 13.6872812006865, 12.9794709702155, 
16.7022952514517, 20.7797978815964, 13.47095641247, 10.4566565720916, 
18.5654248537436, 7.85281265959316, 14.756072196444, 9.46572765295939, 
20.3168649156311, 37.9983552275622, 15.3068612066615, 18.5240834231189, 
16.9813623324711, 8.59893404246519, 9.99833319442129, 9.61985793380893, 
16.0831174424198, 24.0409373084052, 17.8841177212259, 10.5340717040785, 
13.9191115616862, 8.09732466106347, 12.5445871461227, 9.43618920256831, 
21.0081333456037, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 32.7744819435284, 25.4872517153184, 6.09918027279076, 
26.1962147392837, 13.5033946349304, 13.6479546697176, 10.1176413588675, 
19.7855165883195, 13.9298839430437, 28.6856526275186, 6.8239773348588, 
23.1984194863932, 12.654709268358, 18.4842275106824, 4.79235502302017, 
13.1288486420808, 25.7864628568299, 31.8680874857592, 6.17791766428355, 
26.5582692709195, 19.2041662146525, 19.0446842977247, 18.5941298980798, 
18.0205900754295, 11.6790410565251, 28.8946361804401, 4.34357763446985, 
23.2350310235787, 8.88491230495083, 25.7740179250345, 9.23985930628816, 
11.5617905187735, 20.2410474037289, 22.2994768249541, 9.18694726228468, 
17.0117606378646, 17.229819112999, 20.4093524313406, 17.1571170849495, 
11.9558214551183, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 15.0180447018467, 
17.2880016196205, 11.8939760663399, 10.3605823517149, 9.92975326984513, 
18.1457065628943, 9.86618805145466, 7.92254167970524, 17.5499287747842, 
14.7300712829232, 8.01508993503296, 15.5298100439123, 12.3193614553136, 
15.25013661141, 12.7766062264854, 10.7780641428165, 23.0079696337305, 
13.9319776054945, 10.9060380829459, 15.5609018590397, 21.0214176496258, 
14.0558410159857, 23.8189350447636, 15.6314320094695, 16.2777967387072, 
16.3240619944914, 6.17791766428355, 14.4798710859823, 14.770466027403, 
12.076492316342, 13.8759384067048, 12.6912043032435), se = c(13.146450725069, 
6.18117662297757, 10.5280709428545, 5.79031758868007, 5.6134758493389, 
8.99506037284415, 4.51417520459472, 9.63904098503119, 10.4733126458527, 
5.42217668469038, 6.29108716978058, 4.59649625016466, 3.33020686711468, 
6.33771778061052, 4.8346262638503, 8.54465394917261, 14.844424692269, 
6.03139932169789, 6.81868348322786, 6.11509970846302, 3.10756246026439, 
5.58780915127844, 5.29884683471581, 6.81868348322786, 8.48331696134635, 
5.49949492630409, 4.26891216952412, 7.57930295827613, 3.20589734361189, 
6.02414124815959, 3.86436713231718, 8.29432536939161, 15.5127635620908, 
6.2489999199872, 7.56242538989826, 6.93261214197874, 3.51050012264793, 
4.08180243411059, 3.92729055598273, 6.5659052011974, 9.81467155730531, 
7.30116048614496, 4.30051676481379, 5.68245349983419, 3.30571895021004, 
5.12130625697954, 3.85230811044207, 8.57653452417959, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 13.3801262242842, 
10.4051269414009, 2.48997991959775, 10.6945598839368, 5.51273777516923, 
5.57175416224051, 4.13050978828414, 8.07740332312584, 5.68685130610761, 
11.7108686460247, 2.78587708112026, 9.47071509678358, 5.16626342512437, 
7.54615428178118, 1.95647074544389, 5.35983001388829, 10.5272793784107, 
13.010092236414, 2.52212432507026, 10.8423680275318, 7.84006802691575, 
7.77495980697007, 7.5910217435541, 7.35687509144413, 4.76794854558366, 
11.79618582424, 1.77325814376939, 9.48566169425084, 3.62725025941752, 
10.5221987562803, 3.77215676591876, 4.72008121399057, 8.26337299977033, 
9.10372329202606, 3.75055551440939, 6.94502219818867, 7.03404419788345, 
8.33208323956927, 7.00436371921898, 4.88094367014321, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6.1310910756388, 7.05779710674655, 4.85569539590137, 
4.22969003329769, 4.05380479714223, 7.40795368356051, 4.02785440540136, 
3.23436409686836, 7.16472842006823, 6.01352641966426, 3.27214676389132, 
6.34001840165574, 5.02935825373819, 6.22584220094849, 5.21602764989263, 
4.4001262608147, 9.39296427001497, 5.68770604022395, 4.45237140309646, 
6.35271158202893, 8.58195781858662, 5.73827306580802, 9.72403951269453, 
6.38150539536802, 6.64538269109546, 6.66427040267725, 2.52212432507026, 
5.9113826169894, 6.03001750504185, 4.93020734294659, 5.66482813311911, 
5.18116246072679), ci = c(33.7940274369502, 15.889220349886, 
27.0632679299923, 14.8844852160264, 14.4298990530937, 23.1225388048852, 
11.604056783811, 24.7779436690751, 26.922507246369, 13.9381488952758, 
16.1717544050426, 11.8156697682437, 8.56056928151632, 16.2916222062267, 
12.4278024559438, 21.9647322335412, 38.1588084744178, 15.5042055398258, 
17.5279839049389, 15.7193642336799, 7.98824361346093, 14.3639207052787, 
13.6211194231394, 17.5279839049389, 21.8070604867824, 14.1369017627314, 
10.9735880809055, 19.4832185113292, 8.24102147840344, 15.4855480678265, 
9.93367195656454, 21.3212421334155, 39.8768282332316, 16.0635656852119, 
19.4398333406273, 17.8208468456823, 9.02402784927781, 10.4926071937808, 
10.0954217664752, 16.878196644708, 25.2294164279454, 18.7682305247498, 
11.0548302794798, 14.6072117485218, 8.49762108712868, 13.1647368389222, 
9.90267325397684, 22.0466838605638, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 34.3947094306661, 26.7472303130552, 
6.40069715241714, 27.4912413777728, 14.1709435894762, 14.3226500420865, 
10.6178134336812, 20.7636262615357, 14.6185166694449, 30.1037462209939, 
7.16132502104324, 24.3452481982785, 13.280302918737, 19.3980071256559, 
5.02926816019191, 13.7778816757996, 27.0612331488113, 33.4435067828789, 
6.48332697724211, 27.8711943068573, 20.1535364601427, 19.9861704525997, 
19.5133426079005, 18.9114494771115, 12.2564019245259, 30.3230610095818, 
4.55830517426775, 24.3836696502324, 9.32414363016577, 27.0481729938491, 
9.69663766364338, 12.1333550314124, 21.2416765342972, 23.4018657311414, 
9.64110987888638, 17.8527479107548, 18.0815862461422, 21.4183018286465, 
18.0052901468143, 12.5468651392342, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 15.760471351669, 18.1426450422092, 12.4819623840869, 10.872764369967, 
10.4206369767492, 19.0427511781958, 10.3539293711124, 8.31419759724407, 
18.4175207338946, 15.458261782508, 8.41132103479517, 16.2975361408962, 
12.928376971967, 16.0040368732962, 13.4082259309908, 11.3108846405566, 
24.1453833352814, 14.6207138334386, 11.4451850543063, 16.3301649998, 
22.0606248826558, 14.7507005108872, 24.9964393403423, 16.4041818533482, 
17.0825000365819, 17.1310524448908, 6.48332697724211, 15.1956927787292, 
15.5006534670296, 12.6735014416993, 14.5619043009976, 13.318602109025
)), .Names = c("Date", "Treatment", "Heat", "Species", "N", "Average.Stem.Density", 
"sd", "se", "ci"), row.names = c(NA, -144L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Add data via `dput(nzsum)`

Comment: Is it possible to share the data too? i.e. include the output (or a link to the output) of `dput(nzsum)`. That way it'd be easy to reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize your tick marks and labels as much as you like. For example:

```
# Set tick marks on y axis
# a tick mark is shown on every 5
p + scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,40,5))

# Tick marks can be spaced randomly
p + scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(5,7.5, 20, 25))

# Change x and y axis labels, and limits
sp + scale_x_continuous(name="Speed of cars", limits=c(0, 30)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Stopping distance", limits=c(0, 150))
```

You can find full details and lots of examples [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-axis-ticks-a-guide-to-customize-tick-marks-and-labels).

To address your 2nd question I suggest `gap.plot` from `plotrix`.

```
twogrp<-c(rnorm(5)+4,rnorm(5)+20,rnorm(5)+5,rnorm(5)+22)
 gpcol<-c(2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5)
 gap.plot(twogrp,gap=c(8,16),xlab="Index",ylab="Group values",
  main="Gap on Y axis",col=gpcol)
 gap.plot(twogrp,rnorm(20),gap=c(8,16),gap.axis="x",xlab="X values",
  xtics=c(4,7,17,20),ylab="Y values",main="Gap on X axis with added lines")
 gap.plot(c(seq(3.5,7.5,by=0.5),seq(16.5,22.5,by=0.5)),
  rnorm(22),gap=c(8,16),gap.axis="x",type="l",add=TRUE,col=2,)
 gap.plot(twogrp,gap=c(8,16,25,35),
 xlab="X values",ylab="Y values",xlim=c(1,30),ylim=c(0,42),
 main="Test two gap plot with the lot",xtics=seq(0,30,by=5),
 ytics=c(4,6,18,20,22,38,40,42),
 lty=c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10)),
 pch=c(rep(2,10),rep(3,10)),
 col=c(rep(2,10),rep(3,10)),
 type="b")
 gap.plot(21:30,rnorm(10)+40,gap=c(8,16,25,35),add=TRUE,
  lty=rep(3,10),col=rep(4,10),type="l")
```

You could also combine `axis.break` with manual subsetting and re-scaling of the data. By re-scaling I mean that after omitting any range of data you don't want, subtract the size of the range from the observations with greater values, then add the axis break zigzag and change the tick mark labels to reflect where the data was before rescaling.

Comment: @JesseGray Anytime!